# Using Node.js to listen to key events on Redis

Tags: events, node.js, redis, publish-subscribe

I need to know when data is written on specific keys on a Redis store.
Is there any way to listen to Redis key events using Node.js or do I have to use the pub/sub utilities?
In the second case, what would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to listen to Redis key events using Node.js or do I
>   have to use the pub/sub utilities?

As far as I know redis itself doesn't natively support [key change notifications yet](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/83) although there are other [alternatives](http://groups.google.com/group/redis-db/browse_thread/thread/6f51a22a978f202a) including a pub/sub based solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use pubsub, there's lots of opportunities for creative solutions with Redis' blocking operations (BLPOP, BRPOP, BRPOPLPUSH).  You can dedicate a Redis connection in your server to block until a new item is added to a list, and actually add to said list right after you store a key (in a multi exec!).  So, something generic might look like this (you can use two different terminals to simulate two different connections):

Connection 1 (connetion will just hang out after this):

```
BRPOP myfunkeys 0
```

Connection 2:

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> multi
OK
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> set somekey "foo"
QUEUED
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> rpush myfunkeys "somekey:foo"
QUEUED
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> exec
1) OK
2) (integer) 1
redis 127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Back to connection 1 after you EXEC:

```
1) "myfunkeys"
2) "somekey:foo"
(67.51s)
```